# My panel dont close

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity-5

im tring to makeI'm trying to make a button that closes the hack_panel but it didn't work

```
 public class Level1_Controller : MonoBehaviour {
 //Variables
 public Button Hack;
 public Button Develop;
 public Button Research;
 public Button SQ;
 public GameObject Hack_Panel;
 public bool isOpened;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     isOpened = false;
     Hack.onClick.AddListener(Goto_hack);
     Develop.onClick.AddListener(Goto_develop);
     Research.onClick.AddListener(Goto_research);
     SQ.onClick.AddListener(Goto_sq);
 }

 public void Goto_hack() {
     if(isOpened == false) {
         Hack_Panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
     } else {
         Hack_Panel.gameObject.SetActive(false);
     }

 }

 public void Goto_develop() {

 }

 public void Goto_research() {

 }

 public void Goto_sq() {

 }
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     Goto_hack();
     Goto_develop();
     Goto_research();
     Goto_sq();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez porque você nunca atualiza a variável `isOpened` se o `Update()` roda a cada frame e ele executa o `Goto_Hack()`, `isOpened` sempre será false... Aliás não faz sentido algum você executar todos os metédos de clique a cada frame...

Considerando que o comportamento desejado é que o `Hack_Panel` abra e feche ao clicar no botão `Hack`, eu renomearia a variável `isOpened` para algo com mais sentido, como por exemplo `showHackPanel` manipularia ela no evento do botão e no `Update()` faria o controle de estado do `Hack_Panel`... veja exemplo abaixo.

```
 public class Level1_Controller : MonoBehaviour {
     //Variables
     public Button Hack;
     public Button Develop;
     public Button Research;
     public Button SQ;
     public GameObject Hack_Panel;
     public bool showHackPanel = false;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start () {             
         Hack.onClick.AddListener(Goto_hack);
         Develop.onClick.AddListener(Goto_develop);
         Research.onClick.AddListener(Goto_research);
         SQ.onClick.AddListener(Goto_sq);
     }

     public void Goto_hack() {
         showHackPanel =! showHackPanel;
     }

     public void Goto_develop() {

     }

     public void Goto_research() {

     }

     public void Goto_sq() {

     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () {
        Hack_Panel.gameObject.SetActive(showHackPanel);
     }
 }
```

Comment: obrigado leandro